# UIScrollView Starting with blank page in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

I have a horizontal scrollview that should scroll through 5 images. The first image is always blank (black screen), then if you scroll it shows image 1 - 4. My code is below...any obvious reason it isn't just starting on image 1?

```
- (void)setupPage
{
scrollView.delegate = self;

[self.scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];

scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;



NSUInteger nimages = 0;
CGFloat cx = 0;
for (; ; nimages++) {
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"day%d.jpg",      (nimages + 1)];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    if (image == nil) {
        break;
    }
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
    rect.size.height = kScrollObjHeight;
    rect.size.width = kScrollObjWidth;
    rect.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width + cx;
    rect.origin.y = ((scrollView.frame.size.height - image.size.height) / 100);

    imageView.frame = rect;

    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];

    cx += scrollView.frame.size.width;
}

self.pageControl.numberOfPages = nimages;
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(cx, [scrollView bounds].size.height)];
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
rect.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width + cx;
```

should be

```
rect.origin.x = cx;
```